# Can you federate the "default" exchange? Should you federate the "default" exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, messagebroker, rabbitmq-exchange

I'm experimenting with the RabbitMQ and also the Federation plugin. I want to test RabbitMQ Federation with two brokers configured for bi-directional upstream but my sender/receiver python scripts use the "default" exchange ... which does not get Federated.

**Can you federate the "default" exchange? If yes, how? Also if yes, should you (in terms of best-practices, etc) federate the "default" exchange?**

In the short term, I will probably just go with creating a new "hello-exchange" and then federating that and rejiggering my sender/receiver to use this new exchange.

Comment: You can't federate the default-exchange https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-federation/blob/master/src/rabbit_federation_exchange.erl#L86

Answer (score 0):

No you can't Federate the "default" exchange. I found the official documentation for it: https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-exchanges.html. Somehow I missed this part of the documentation.

(Also see @Gabriele's comment for the direct github sourcecode if you want to see more lowlevel (and it says why... but the "why" is also very lowlevel).)